# Qt 5.2.1: cannot parse date/time

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qdatetime

I am having a problem in parsing a date from QString using Qt 5.2.1...

I am using the following code:

```
QString value = "1979-10-27T04:00:00.000";
QDateTime dt = QDateTime::fromString(value, "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'zzz");
```

but the returned `QDateTime` is invalid... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are those single quotes supposed to be there in your format string?

Comment: There is no problem with your code. It is valid when i run it.

Comment: @Jongware, nope, not a dupe, the format here is correct. Morix, what do you mean by *invalid*? Which datetime value does your code return?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: you're right, I agree. Retracted to prevent others clicking "oh that must be it" :-)

Comment: Your code as-is works for me inside a dummy main. How are you determining that the date is invalid?

Comment: Please see my own answer here below... thanks for your help anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely due to the following bug in Creator:

[GDB pretty printer for QDateTime is broken, shows “(invalid)” even when QDateTime is not invalid](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-11164)

According to the latest comment (01/Apr/14), it now displays a valid date until it's expanded:

> It looks much better now. QDateTime shows a human-readable format. Only when I try to expand it, it becomes "not accessible".

I'd recommend upgrading your version of Creator.

With as many users as Qt has, you'll often find existing bug reports for your problem if you have a quick search through Jira.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys for you help: I think that the problem is definitively related to QtCreator (or at least to the debugger)...

I said that the `QDateTime` was not valid because the expression watch of QtCreator told me so (as you can see from the screenshot here below)... But if I `qDebug()` my datetime, then it appears correct...

[image: Screenshot from my PC]